# Increase the speed of GKAgent

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, gameplay-kit

I'm developing a game with gameplaykit, I'm trying to increase the game speed with `worldNode.speed = 4.0`.

The animations are faster but the agent (GKAgent) with a certain behavior does not increase speed to move in certain point.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: The `speed` property affects `SKAction`s not agents. You'll need to adjust the agent's `mass`, `maxAcceleration`, and/or `maxSpeed`.

Comment: It was what I thought, is very complex to do for every agent. Perform a lot of effort

Comment: @0x141E I went around the problem with a simple trick that works!

Answer (score 0):

I post my solution, a simple trick that works:

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

        if worldNode.paused { return }

        guard entityManagerGame != nil else { return }

        let deltaTimeForSpeed = CFTimeInterval(deltaTime * Double(worldNode.speed))
        entityManagerGame.update(deltaTimeForSpeed)
}
```